# Debugging app started from intent-filter (custom file extension)

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have a custom file extension that I've coded and can load it using, for example, a file manager.

However two things:

1. How can I debug my app (in eclipse) from starting it via the intent filter from file manager as there are a few issues and I'd like to go through it in the debugger.
2. Is there a way to set an icon so when I browse my custom file extension in a file manager I can see my app's launcher icon rather than the plain white rectangle I see?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug, put a dialog in onResume() so that your app will pause for input (or some other way of doing this).  When it starts, use the debugger to attach to your apps process, e.g. in Studio, `Run->Attach debugger to Android process`.

For an icon in the chooser, use this:

```
<intent-filter android:icon="drawable resource"
    ...
</intent-filter>
```

For browsing, nothing you can do since you do not "own" the extension, you just advertise an intent for it.

Comment: Thanks, blocking it worked fine. Trying not to get into too much trouble from Stack overflow, when I translate the file into:
file:///mnt/sdcard/download/sampleguide.amg

(I added file:// to the start) when I try and load it I get a file not found exception. I've added external file writing. Any idea?

Comment: Please show just the bi of code where you are opening the file in a new question.

Comment: Cheers, erm my fault I was concocting the wrong uri, it's all working now. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just put your code in `onNewIntent()`, start the app by debugging as usual, close the app by pressing the home button, open a file in a file manager.
2. No, most file managers come with their own file icons, and at least there is no way to set an icon for your file type in all file managers. File managers in general are no default feature in Android, so there is no way to somehow set a file icon.

Comment: Thanks, that only works if you call single top? i just used the blocking approach above as it was less code :)

As for the icon, I guess I assumed it would find it if the manifest registered it.